# Processing Delta feed data in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I am building a data warehouse currently that processes data (for the sake of this question, let's just say one table) from a table that is updated every 15 minutes. My process stores a snapshot of the table and then compares the refreshed version with the snapshot and then stores the difference - or delta - in a separate staging table that will then be processed at the end of the day. At the end of the day I want a row describing the name of the column that has changed with a timestamp, to be then used when create snapshots at any point in time. It is worth noting that by the end of the day, there can be multiple rows for each unique identifier created i.e. a row for every change someone might have actioned during the day. So, I am stuck on the last part. I found this clever link [Return column Names of Changed values with XML](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic991010-338-1.aspx) but the problem is this is very inefficient when processing thousands of rows. I would be grateful to anyone who has
any ideas on a more appropriate solution (excluding change Data Capture)?
Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned excluding CDC as a solution but what about [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server)?

Comment: Hi Dan. I'm not sure it will work because I create a table based on a view, and then recreate the table from the same view and compare it from a temporary table to get the delta. I don't know much about Change Tracking but I'm guessing it wont work on a table that is dropped and then recreated?

Comment: Okay, well as I could find no other way, I have ended up using the XML link I quoted above in conjunction with a hard-coded comparison of the final table and the staging table. So I use the XML example link above to create a table that stores what values have changed with a time stamp on them, and then updated the final table with the values from the staging table where appropriate. I have added the basic code below...

Answer (score 0):

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHistory') is Not Null
 drop table #TempHistory

 -- I just made up a few column here, there are LOADS of them in the real query but for Governance of course...
SELECT 
distinct
a.ClaimId,
a.FirstName,
a.Surname,
a.Incident,
a.Total,
a.extractDate -- this field is create by ETL process
into #temphistory

FROM [Data Mart Test].[Staging].[Claim] a JOIN [Data Mart Test].[dbo].[Claim] b
ON a.ClaimId = b.ClaimId
WHERE
ISNULL(a.ClaimId,0) <> ISNULL(b.ClaimId,0) OR 
ISNULL(a.FirstName,'') <> ISNULL(b.FirstName,'') OR
ISNULL(a.Surname,'') <> ISNULL(b.Surname,'') OR 
ISNULL(a.Incident,'') <> ISNULL(b.Incident,'')  OR
ISNULL(a.Total,0.0) <> ISNULL(b.Total,0.0) OR 

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHistoryA') is Not Null
 drop table #TempHistoryA
  select 
  * 
  , 1 as Version

   into #TempHistoryA

   FROM [Data Mart Test].[dbo].[Claim] where ClaimID in (select distinct claimid  FROM #TempHistory)




 if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHistoryB') is Not Null
 drop table #TempHistoryB
  SELECT  *
      ,(RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [ClaimId] ORDER BY [ExtractDate])) + 1 as Version

      into #TempHistoryB

  FROM [Data Mart Test].[Staging].[Claim]where ClaimID in (select distinct claimid  FROM #TempHistory)



 if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempChanges') is Not Null
 drop table #TempChanges

DECLARE @x xml

SET @x = (
   SELECT 
        t2.ClaimID AS [@key]
      , t2.Version AS [@version]
      , ( SELECT t1.* FOR XML PATH('t1'), TYPE ) AS [*]
      , ( SELECT t2.* FOR XML PATH('t2'), TYPE ) AS [*]
   FROM #TempHistoryA AS t1
   INNER JOIN #TempHistoryB AS t2
   ON t1.ClaimID = t2.ClaimID
   AND t1.Version = t2.Version - 1
   FOR XML PATH('row'), ROOT('root')
   );

WITH Nodes AS (
   SELECT
        C.value('../../@key', 'int') AS [Key]
      , C.value('../../@version', 'int') AS Version_ID
      , C.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(255)')AS Version_Alias
      , C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS Field
      , C.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS Val
   FROM @x.nodes('/root/row/*/*') AS T(C)
   )

SELECT 
[Key] as ClaimID,
x.ExtractDate, 
Field
, Max(CASE Version_Alias WHEN 't1' THEN Val END) AS [Initial Value]
, Max(CASE Version_Alias WHEN 't2' THEN Val END) AS [New Value]

Into #TempChanges

FROM [Nodes]v
inner join [#TempHistoryB]x on x.ClaimId = v.[Key]
                    and x.Version = v.Version_ID
where Field not in ( 'ExtractDate','Version')

GROUP BY 
[Key],
x.ExtractDate,
Field
HAVING Max(CASE Version_Alias WHEN 't1' THEN Val END) <> Max(CASE Version_Alias WHEN 't2' THEN Val END)





--Find records in [Data Mart Test].dbo.Claim that are not in [Data Mart Test].Staging.Claim
SELECT 
*
FROM [Data Mart Test].dbo.Claim 
WHERE ClaimId NOT IN (SELECT b.ClaimId FROM [Data Mart Test].Staging.Claim b)




delete from  [Data Mart Test].[dbo].[Claim] where ClaimID in (select distinct claimid  FROM #TempHistory)

delete from [#TempHistoryB] 
where not exists
(
select
*
from

(select 
claimid, 
max(Version) as LastVersion  
FROM #TempHistoryB b

group by ClaimId
)  b
where b.ClaimId = claimid
    and b.LastVersion = Version
)

insert into [Data Mart Test].[dbo].[Claim]
select
[ClaimId]
      --a whole lot of other columns
      from #TempHistoryB
```

Comment: It ain't pretty, I know and I kept the temporary tables in this example because it makes it easier to check but they could easily be replaced by CTE's etc... Maybe someone else has a more elegant solution?